# resultSet.next() returns false, even though table is populated

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, resultset

I have a few functions that help with retrieving the objects from the database.

```
public User getUser(int beamID) throws NoSuchUserException {
    return userFromResultSet(getUserResultSet(beamID));
}


private ResultSet getUserResultSet(int beamID) {
    try(Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {

        // queries.getUserByBeamID() returns "SELECT * FROM user WHERE beamID=?"
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(queries.getUserByBeamID());

        stmt.setInt(1, beamID);
        System.out.println(stmt.toString());
        return stmt.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}

private User userFromResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) {
    try {
        boolean next = resultSet.next();  // Debugger tells me this is false.
        if (!next)
            throw new NoSuchUserException();

        User user = new User(this,
             resultSet.getInt("beamID"),
             resultSet.getString("name"),
             resultSet.getInt("points"),
             resultSet.getInt("time")
        );

        if (resultSet.next())
            throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicate user entries exist - database integrity compromised!");

        return user;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

The strange thing is, I know the data *does* exist for two reasons:

- My program tries to create the entry if it does not exist, **but attempting that gives an error that the unique constraint isn't being followed**.
- Running the query in my SQLite DB browser works just fine:

[image: The query returns a result, as it should.]

I highly doubt that this is an issue with uncommitted data, as this is a file-based database, and opening that file with a text editor shows instances of the usernames in the data.

Comment: "My program tries to create the entry if it does not exist, **but attempting that gives an error that the unique constraint isn't being followed.**" -- so, that means that the user does **not** exist (or else it wouldn't attempt to create it, which resulted in the unique constraint violation), but the unique constraint is likely on `id` (instead of or in addition to `beam_id`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look closely at what you are doing here:

```
try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(queries.getUserByBeamID());

    stmt.setInt(1, beamID);
    System.out.println(stmt.toString());
    return stmt.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

I believe it is the contract of try-with-resources to guarantee closing the resource specified in the `try` clause, after the expression finishes executing.  I believe that the result set is also being closed at the end of the `try` block, hence calling `next()` returns false, because nothing is there.

The way I would have written your code is to populate the `User` POJO inside the `try` block, and return a `User` object instead of returning a result set:

```
private User getUserResultSet(int beamID) {
    User user = null;
    try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(queries.getUserByBeamID());

        stmt.setInt(1, beamID);

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        user = new User(this,
            rs.getInt("beamID"),
            rs.getString("name"),
            rs.getInt("points"),
            rs.getInt("time")
        );

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    return user;
}
```

Now your separation of concerns is better than before.  Should something go wrong with the connection, result set, etc., it is handled in the actual code which deals with those things.  In the event of an exception or other error, a `null` user object would be returned, and you should update your code to handle this possibility.

Comment: That's a good point, but: the javadoc of `ResultSet.next()` states that it throws an "SQLException if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set". So if that were the reason, the OP should have received a SQLException, not `false`. But it's possible the the driver is broken and doesn't implement the JDBC spec correctly.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt This crossed my mind as well, but from what I read the behavior is driver-specific.  If you have a better explanation for the _result set_ being empty on a valid query, then feel free to post an answer.

Comment: This, in fact, solved it; I nested the usage of the ResultSet inside the try-with-resources, and it worked just fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added a comment to the question already, since the OP's comment about the function that inserts a user "if it doesn't exist" is contradictory.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, the issue was that the `ResultSet` was closed early, making it *behave* as though all the data was processed, or in this case, that the query returned an empty set. Because of this, my program acted as though the user didn't exist, even though it did.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer addresses the root cause of the problem the actual implementation has some issues.

- `Exceptions` are swallowed
- `PreparedStatement` should be closed independently of the `Connection`
- `ResultSet` should be closed independently of the `PreparedStatement` or the `Connection`
- It does not handle `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` `ResultSets` that throw on `ResultSet.next()` when they are empty
- It does not check that the result is unique
- It does not have proper logging

A more complete example is below:

```java
package com.stackoverflow.questions.Q42327984;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import lombok.Value;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class Answer {

    /**
     * <p>
     * We use lombok's {@link Log4j2} annotation to create a Log4j2 logger, avoid using {@link System#out},
     * {@link System#err} or {@link Throwable#printStackTrace()}
     * </p>
     *
     * @See Lombok's <a href="https://www.projectlombok.org/features/log">log</a> api.
     * @See Log4j2's install <a href="https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html">guide</a>.
     */
    @Log4j2
    static class UserDao {

        final DataSource dataSource;

        final UserQueries queries;

        public UserDao(final DataSource dataSource, final UserQueries queries) {
            this.dataSource = dataSource;
            this.queries = queries;
        }
        /**
         * Find {@link User} by beam id.
         * <p>
         * In most systems not finding a User would not be an "exceptional" condition, we should return {@link Optional}
         * instead of throwing an {@link Exception}
         * </p>
         * <p>
         * 'get' is fine for bean like things, but 'find' is for queries
         * </p>
         * <p>
         * We add "ByBeamId" so we can disambiguate between this method and other queries that might also find
         * {@link User} by a int value.
         * </p>
         *
         * @param beamID the beam ID
         * @return the {@link Optional} {@link User}, null's are the "billion dollar mistake"
         * @throws {@link NoSuchUserException} the no such user exception
         */
        public Optional<User> findUserByBeamId(int beamID) throws NoSuchUserException {

            log.debug("findUserByBeamId({})", beamID);

            final String userByBeamID = this.queries.getUserByBeamID();
            log.debug("findUserByBeamId({}) userByBeamID query: {}", beamID, userByBeamID);

            try (final Connection conn = this.dataSource.getConnection();
                    final PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(userByBeamID)) {

                stmt.setInt(1, beamID);

                /*
                 * ResultSets should be closed properly also
                 */
                try (final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {

                    /*
                     * There are other ways to find if the ResultSet is empty but the method below is safe and
                     * can handle most implementations
                     */
                    int resultSetType = rs.getType();

                    try {

                        boolean scrolledForwardToRow = rs.next();

                        if (!scrolledForwardToRow) {
                            return Optional.empty();
                        }

                    } catch (SQLException e) {

                        /*
                         * ResultSets of TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY can throw a SQLException on ResultSet.next() if the ResultSet
                         * is
                         * empty.
                         */
                        if (ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY == resultSetType) {
                            log.debug(
                                    "findUserByBeamId({}): initial rs.next() call failed but ResultSet is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY so returning empty.",
                                    userByBeamID, e);
                            return Optional.empty();
                        }

                        log.error("findUserByBeamId({}): initial rs.next() call failed, return empty.", userByBeamID,
                                e);
                        throw e;
                    }

                    /*
                     * User should not have a reference to its DAO, this is a recipe for trouble.
                     *
                     * In general User should be an interface and a static factory method or a builder should be used
                     * for construction.
                     * 'new' should be avoided as it tightly couples a specific implementation of User.
                     *
                     * User user = new User(this,
                     * rs.getInt("beamID"),
                     * rs.getString("name"),
                     * rs.getInt("points"),
                     * rs.getInt("time"));
                     */

                    /*
                     * Assigning to local variables has a couple advantages:
                     * - It makes stepping through the debugger much easier.
                     * - When an exception occurs the line number in the stack trace will only contain one method.
                     *
                     * Note, that the performance impact of local variables is not significant in a method of this
                     * complexity with so many external calls.
                     */

                    final int beamIDFromRs = rs.getInt("beamID");
                    final String name = rs.getString("name");
                    final int points = rs.getInt("points");
                    final int time = rs.getInt("time");

                    final User user = User.of(beamIDFromRs, name, points, time);

                    /*
                     * Before we return our result we need to make sure it was unique.
                     *
                     * There are other ways to find if the ResultSet has no more row but the method below is safe
                     * can handle most implementations.
                     */
                    try {

                        boolean scrolledForward = rs.next();

                        if (!scrolledForward) {
                            return Optional.of(user);
                        }

                    } catch (SQLException se) {

                        /*
                         * ResultSets of TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY can throw a SQLException on ResultSet.next() if the ResultSet
                         * is
                         * empty.
                         */
                        if (ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY == resultSetType) {

                            log.debug(
                                    "findUserByBeamId({}): rs.next() call failed but ResultSet is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY so returning user: {}.",
                                    userByBeamID, user, se);

                            return Optional.of(user);
                        }

                        log.error("findUserByBeamId({}): rs.next() call failed.", userByBeamID, se);

                        throw se;

                    }

                    log.error("findUserByBeamId({}): results not unique.", userByBeamID);

                    throw new IllegalStateException("findUserByBeamId(" + beamID + ") results were not unique.");
                }

            } catch (SQLException se) {

                log.error("findUserByBeamId({}): failed", userByBeamID, se);

                throw new IllegalStateException("findUserByBeamId(" + beamID + ") failed", se);
            }

        }
        /**
         * Gets the user.
         *
         * @param beamID the beam ID
         * @return the {@link User}
         * @throws NoSuchUserException if the user does not exist.
         * @deprecated use {@link #findUserByBeamId(int)}
         */
        @Deprecated
        public User getUser(final int beamID) throws NoSuchUserException {
            return findUserByBeamId(beamID).orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchUserException(beamID));
        }

    }

    interface UserQueries {
        String getUserByBeamID();
    }

    /**
     * Use interfaces to avoid tight coupling
     */
    interface User {

        /**
         * static factory method for creating User instances
         *
         * @param beamID the beam ID
         * @param name the name
         * @param points the points
         * @param time the time
         * @return the user
         */
        static User of(final int beamID, final String name, final int points, final int time) {
            return new DefaultUser(beamID, name, points, time);
        }

        /**
         * Gets the beam ID.
         *
         * @return the beam ID
         */
        int getBeamID();

        /**
         * Gets the name.
         *
         * @return the name
         */
        String getName();

        /**
         * Gets the points.
         *
         * @return the points
         */
        int getPoints();

        /**
         * Gets the time.
         *
         * @return the time
         */
        int getTime();
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * We use lombok's {@link Value} to create a final immutable object with an all args constuctor
     * ({@link #DefaultUser(int, String, int, int)} and proper
     * {@link #toString()}, {@link #equals(Object)} and {@link #hashCode()} methods
     * </p>
     *
     * @See Lombok's <a href="https://www.projectlombok.org/features/Value">value</a> api.
     */
    @Value
    static class DefaultUser implements User {

        final int beamID;

        final String name;

        final int points;

        final int time;
    }

    /**
     * The Class NoSuchUserException.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class NoSuchUserException extends RuntimeException {

        final int beamID;

        public NoSuchUserException(int beamID) {
            this.beamID = beamID;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the beam ID.
         *
         * @return the beam ID
         */
        public int getBeamID() {
            return this.beamID;
        }

    }
}
```